# vuejs jquery issue when trying to import bootstrap

Tags: jquery, vue.js, webpack, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js

I can't import bootstrap (modal, ...) in a vue component using installed packages (bootstrap, popper.js, jquery). I'm also using nuxtjs here.

I directly get :

[image]

I created a simple/bare repo to show you the error : https://github.com/fdouchant/nuxt-bootstrap-issue
the import is located in [this component](https://github.com/fdouchant/nuxt-bootstrap-issue/blob/master/components/BootstrapModal.vue)

PS: I don't want to use bootstrap-vue since it's overkill for such a small feature

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some import can't be done server-side. Using jQuery functions that are not activated on the server (maybe using window or some other global not available).

I had to require the package in the mounted function (only triggered client-side).

Find my nuxtjs issue there : https://cmty.app/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/c10474